# Sonarqube-Failed to reset file system

Tags: sonarqube

Hi i have installed sonarqube 5.6.6 and able to open localhost:9000
but wouldn't start the services for sonarqube it shows a 1067 error.

[image: ERROR in lOG]

Comment: Please provide the full log and your installation information (sonar.conf, Windows version, Java version), without those information noone will be able to answer such generic question.

Comment: And please don't send stacktrace as an image but as plain text please !